# Web project with Angular in frontend and Symfony2 in Backend

Tags: angularjs, rest, symfony, communication

I would like to have a web app with Angular in Frontend and Symfony in Backend. I separated this into 2 single projects and now I want to let them communicate via REST.

Now here's the point I'm struggling a little. First of all, is the project separation the right approach? Also, I'm confused with building a REST-Service with the ngResource-factory in Angular. Can someone explain this to me, how to create a simple GET-Request (no params etc and just how to use the factory. Dependencies aren't a problem)? The tutorial on AngularJS doesn't really help. Do I need to create a JSON-File as well?

By the way, I'm new to these 2 frameworks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As Sample, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/mbiagetti/acme-social-frontend) project as frontend, and [this](https://github.com/mbiagetti/acme-social-backend) as backend of the same app

Comment: Thanks for your Support. I got it working after I read the tutorial again. There was a misunderstanding in the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of API Platform

Take a look at [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/). It's a solution to create REST API using Symfony (full stack).

[The official tutorial](https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/getting-started/) explains how to create a REST API in a first project then an Angular client (using Restangular) in another project.